# GKE Multicluster Ingress for private clusters with on-premise hardware load balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

It appears that istio based or MultiCluster Ingress on GKE  will only work with External Load balancers. We have a need(due to a regulatory limitation) that allows external traffic ingress only via an on premise hardware load balancer, this traffic must then be routed to GCP via partner interconnect.

With such a setup - supposing we create an a static IP with an internal load balancer on GCP - Will a MultiCluster Ingress work with this Internal load balancer?

Alternatively, how would you design a solution if you have multiple GKE clusters that need to be load balanced with this type of on-premise hardware LB type ingress?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more you requirements? Your users are onPrem and they have to connect via Partner Internconnect to clusters on GKE ?

Comment: Hi Abdel, Our users are external and coming in from the public internet. We have some regulatory limitations that prevents us from using direct ingress from public internet to gcp. We have a partner interconnect to on premise systems and all external ingress is via on prem F5 hardware appliance and then on to gcp via the interconnect. Traffic is routed via cloud router to shared vpc project.

Answer (score 0):

MultiCluster Ingress only supports Public LoadBalancers.

You can use the new Gateway API with the gke-l7-rilb-mc Gateway Class, this should deploy an internal Multi cluster L7 LoadBalancer. You can route external traffic thought you onprem F5 and via Partner Interconnect to GCP to the LoadBalancer provisioned via the Gateway API

Just keep in mind that the Gateway API and controller are still in preview for now, they should be GA by the eoy https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-multi-cluster-gateways#blue-green